# C# Splitting a word into characters and then summing the ASCII code of each letter to get a sum

Tags: c#

how can I split a word into characters and then sum all of the ASCII codes to get an integer sum?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uisng LINQ, this can be done as below (`input` is your string):

```
var sum = input.Sum(ch=>(int)ch);
```

Otherwise you could use a `foreach` statement and loop through the string's characters:

```
var sum = 0;
foreach(var ch in input)
{
    sum += (int)ch;
}
```

Comment: `.ToCharArray()` is unnecessary. `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: Can someone solve this? Write a program to calculate points for all players and find who the winner is. You will be given the count of the players, their names and initial scores. Score for every player depends on his name. To the player score add or subtract the ASCII code of each letter. If ASCII code is even add it to the score. If is odd – subtract it from the score. Find the one with highest score and print his name and score on the console. If two or more players are with same points – the winner is the first one.

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like please do my homework. You need to do some work on it yourself and ask for help on specifics where you get stuck. Have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Why not omit `Select` and have the lambda arrow inside `Sum`? It has [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx) for that. With @Dennis_E's suggestion it becomes: `var sum = input.Sum(ch => (int)ch);`